# Canvas not being updated when @State variable animates

Tags: swift, canvas, swiftui, swiftui-animation

Why isn't Canvas getting updates on animated @State variables?

For example when I animate the rotationAngle as seen here:

```
@State private var rotationAngle: Double = 90.0

HStack {
    Canvas() {
        print(rotationAngle) //prints 90.0 at the start, 0.0 when the animation starts
    }
}
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 2)) {
        rotationAngle = 0.0
    }
}
```

The same animation works fine in any other case at the same time. All views containing reference to the rotationAngle get updated, except Canvas.

Is there any other solution, can I access the value of rotationAngle while it's being animated?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-custom-animated-drawings-with-timelineview-and-canvas

Comment: Wrap Canvas into `TimelineView(.animation) { timeline in }`

Comment: Canvas body is none declarative so its work like normal uikit code

Comment: Already animating with timeline, the idea was to access the variable from inside the Canvas, but whenever I read it - it is the non-transitional value; in this case 90.0 or 0.0. That's why I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to track the value "in transition" in any way.

Comment: I mean interpolated values. @SPatel

Comment: When you implement Canvas, your are responsible for the interpolated values yourself. It is the a related idea as the `Animatable` protocol